# C# dateTime in javascript method

Tags: javascript, datetime, telerik-grid

I am using javascript to format a C# dateTime field and displays it as dd-mon-yyyy in a grid. But when I pass C# datetime to javascript variable, it is geting converted based on my system timezone. ie, **Fri Aug 31 2012 06:59:14** is converted to **Fri Aug 31 2012 11:29:14 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)** when my machine is in India Standard Time. How to avoid it? I dont have any option other than using javascript since I am using telerik grid.

Comment: I would be shocked if the Telerik grid didn't allow you to specify a format or conversion.

Comment: I am using their clienttemplate to bind data to column and it needs directly bind model property to grid or call a javascript method. I cant use any server side extensions

Answer (score 1):

it do not make any change if you are using c# or anything else as you are using javascript for the conversion every where javascript will be the same..

one other solution is convert the c# date and time to string and in javascript parse that date string to date and see what happens.

check the following code to convert timezone

```
// function to calculate local time
// in a different city
// given the city's UTC offset
function calcTime(city, offset) {

    // create Date object for current location
    // here you can pass your own date also
    d = new Date();

    // convert to msec
    // add local time zone offset 
    // get UTC time in msec
    utc = d.getTime() + (d.getTimezoneOffset() * 60000);

    // create new Date object for different city
    // using supplied offset
    nd = new Date(utc + (3600000*offset));

    // return time as a string
    return "The local time in " + city + " is " + nd.toLocaleString();

}
```

refer : http://www.techrepublic.com/article/convert-the-local-time-to-another-time-zone-with-this-javascript/6016329

Comment: I am calling a JS method \n  function formatDatesOnGrid(chashDateTime, format) {alert(chashDateTime);} and the object chashDateTime is a c# dateTime object and the behaviour i told above is happening

Comment: one solution is convert the c# date and time to string and in javascript parse that date string to date and see what happens..